# Stuck in a git rebase ... how to reset

Tags: git, rebase

I am part way through a git rebase and I am stuck. I can't remember exactly what happened but I was using a UI and deleted a checked-out branch and things just seemed to go blank. I restarted and managed to do a bit of other work creating and committing to other branches etc but then I noticed a status saying I was still in the middle of a rebase

If I try

```
git rebase --skip
git rebase --continue
git rebase --abort
```

each fail with

```
error: could not read '.git/rebase-merge/head-name': No such file or directory
```

Is there a way I can get back to a stable state? I'm really not bothered about what the rebase related to so am not trying to get back to point where I am still in the middle of the rebase.

Edit:

```
$ git status
On branch fix/SJW-01225
Your branch is up to date with 'core-v3/fix/SJW-01225'.

You are currently rebasing.
(all conflicts fixed: run "git rebase --continue")

Untracked files:
(use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

     [long list of untracked files]

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

Edit-1:

```
$ touch .git/rebase-merge/head-name

$ git rebase --abort
error: could not read '.git/rebase-merge/onto': No such file or directory

$ touch .git/rebase-merge/onto

$ git rebase --abort
error: could not get 'onto': ''
```

Thx

Comment: Could you paste what git return when you type git status ?

Comment: Try to create the file: `touch .git/rebase-merge/head-name`.

Comment: TVM. Edited again following your suggestion

Comment: Is this a learning experiment? Perhaps it's `git clone` time?

Comment: Unfortunately not!

Comment: https://xkcd.com/1597/

Answer (score 63, accepted):

To escape from corrupted `git rebase` you can do the following

1. Reset to a known state. You can find out from which commit you started your `rebase` with `git reflog`.

For example, `reflog` will give you the following. The rebase starting point is  the last `rebase (start)` or `rebase -i (start)` if you did an interactive rebase. Here it is `HEAD@{1}`:

```bash
$ git reflog
f10ccfed (HEAD) HEAD@{0}: rebase : fast-forward
383aa038 (origin/master, origin/HEAD) HEAD@{1}: rebase (start): checkout HEAD~10
0600cf7e (origin/Files, master, Files) HEAD@{4}: checkout: moving from master to Files
0600cf7e (origin/Files, master, Files) HEAD@{5}: commit: fixes
f10ccfed (HEAD) HEAD@{6}: commit: refactoring
```

So what you need is:

```bash
git checkout master # assuming you were on master
git reset --hard HEAD@{1}
```

2. Remove the `rebase-merge` folder

```bash
rm -rf .git/rebase-merge
```

Comment: In Windows, I needed to quote the commit. `git reset --hard "HEAD@{1}"`

Comment: In mycase, it cannot find rebase-merge folder.  After resetting Head, I ran rebase --abort and it is fine.

Answer (score 22):

I somehow got my repo into the same state. In my case, there was no `.git/rebase-merge` directory, but I did find a `rebase-apply` directory. Other than the in-progress rebase, `git status` was clean, so the only thing I needed to do to get out of the weird bad rebase state was to run:

```
rm -rf .git/rebase-apply/
```

Answer (score 21):

`git rebase --quit` worked for me.

Comment: Take note of the difference between `--abort` and `--quit`: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55431768/2745495. Using `--quit` does not move the HEAD back, and the original question was: "*Is there a way I can get back to a stable state?*"

Answer (score 1):

I was in a similar problem:

```
$ git status
On branch master
You are currently rebasing.
  (all conflicts fixed: run "git rebase --continue")
nothing to commit, working tree clean
$ git rebase --abort
error: could not read '.git/rebase-merge/head-name': No such file or directory
$ git rebase --skip
error: could not read '.git/rebase-merge/head-name': No such file or directory
$ git rebase --continue
error: could not read '.git/rebase-merge/head-name': No such file or directory
```

So then I tried initiating a new rebase, and I got this clue (first time I've seen Git refer to itself in the first person, by the way):

```
$ git rebase -i HEAD~1
fatal: It seems that there is already a rebase-merge directory, and
I wonder if you are in the middle of another rebase.  If that is the
case, please try
    git rebase (--continue | --abort | --skip)
If that is not the case, please
    rm -fr ".git/rebase-merge"
and run me again.  I am stopping in case you still have something
valuable there.
$ rm -fr ".git/rebase-merge"
$ git status
On branch master
nothing to commit, working tree clean
$ git push origin master
Everything up-to-date
```

**So in my case, the problem was solved by forcefully and recursively removing Git's rebase-merge directory via `rm -fr ".git/rebase-merge"`.**

Answer (score 1):

Encountered a similar issue where `--abort` did not work

```
$ git rebase master
error: could not write index
fatal: Could not detach HEAD
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
```

and could not find anything wrong with the repo using

```
$ git status
On branch XXX
nothing to commit, working tree clean
$ ls .git/r*
#Nothing of interest
```

In the I fixed it by cleaning, i.e. issuing the following (**very destructive if you have uncomitted changes)** command

```
git clean -xfd
```