# What's different between `--abort` and `--quit` as sequencer subcommands for `cherry-pick`?

Tags: git, git-cherry-pick

As per the [doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick#_sequencer_subcommands), among the three sequencer subcommands for `cherry-pick`, we have these two which are, to me, oddly similar :

```
--quit
```

> Forget about the current operation in progress. Can be used to clear the sequencer state after a failed cherry-pick or revert.

```
--abort
```

> Cancel the operation and return to the pre-sequence state.

---

So far I've always used `--abort`, and it works great. What would be a use-case where `--quit` is different/preferable?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you remember that `git rebase` is a sequence of `git cherry-pick` operations,<sup>1</sup> plus a couple of useful gimmicks at the start and end, it makes more sense.

Imagine you have the following series of commits:

```
...--o--*--...--o   <-- mainline
         \
          A--B--C   <-- feature
```

You want to bring `feature` up to date with `mainline` so you:

```
git checkout feature
git rebase mainline
```

Git starts out by enumerating the commits reachable from `feature` (`C`, `B`, `A`, `*`, ...) and those reachable from `mainline` (unnamed, ..., `*`, ...).  It subtracts the `mainline` set from the `feature` set<sup>2</sup> and uses the reverse topological order so that it now has hash IDs `A`, `B`, and `C` listed in the thing that Git calls the *sequencer*.  (The sequencer also records the operation, in this case rebase / cherry-pick.  The sequencer is also used for multiple reverts.  The sequencer can stop partway through, then be resumed with `--continue`.  This is why it needs to know the operation: are we continuing a cherry-pick, a revert, or a rebase?)

Git then detaches `HEAD` at the commit at the tip of `mainline` and runs the op, whatever it is, via the sequencer.  Since the op is "rebase", each step of the sequencer is a simple one-commit cherry-pick:

```
(with)

...--o--*--...--o   <-- mainline, HEAD
         \
          A--B--C   <-- feature

(execute git cherry-pick A to produce)

                  A'   <-- HEAD
                 /
...--o--*--...--o   <-- mainline
         \
          A--B--C   <-- feature
```

This can fail with a merge conflict.  If so, the sequencer halts, leaving you a mess of merge conflicts in your index and work-tree.  You can fix them and resume the sequencer (which will commit for you to make `A'` if needed, if you did not make `A'` yourself), or choose one of the two kinds of stop, "abort" or "quit".  If you resume—or if things went well—we go on to (attempt to) cherry-pick `B`:

```
                  A'-B'   <-- HEAD
                 /
...--o--*--...--o   <-- mainline
         \
          A--B--C   <-- feature
```

Let's say that also succeeds and we go on to attempt to cherry-pick `C` but this attempt *fails*.  The sequencer stops, leaving you a mess in your index and work-tree, with the same graph we see above: `A'` and `B'` exist but `C'` does not.

Let's say we decide to stop: that completing the cherry-pick of `C` is too hard for the moment and we need to back off and do something else for a bit.  You now have the two options, *abort* or *quit*.

If you choose `--abort`, Git re-attaches your `HEAD` to `feature`, giving:

```
...--o--*--...--o   <-- mainline
         \
          A--B--C   <-- feature (HEAD)
```

Where are `A'` and `B'`?  Well, if you know what you're doing, you can fish them out of the reflogs, or you already cleverly attached a branch or tag name to `B'` *before* choosing `--abort`.  But if you choose `--quit`, Git terminates the rebase *without moving `HEAD`*, so that you wind up with:

```
                  A'-B'   <-- HEAD
                 /
...--o--*--...--o   <-- mainline
         \
          A--B--C   <-- feature
```

but can get yourself a clean index and work-tree with `git reset --hard` now.  (Or, you can leave the mess in place.)  So you don't *have* to be clever enough to attach a branch name *before* the `--quit`.

That's basically all there is to it. :-)  But after a long and frustrating rebase with a *lot* of conflicts, where you want to save what you've achieved so far and go back to non-rebase work before coming back at the rebase again later, the "quit" variant feels more satisfying somehow.

(I think what's really missing here is the option to save the remainder of the sequencer state, and restore it later.  However, the sequencer state is per-worktree, so if you have an ongoing rebase task and have to interrupt it with a higher priority task, you can just add a work-tree for the higher priority task.  The various bugs in added work-trees through Git 2.15 is not all that confidence-inspiring, but they do seem to behave well now.  Added work-trees also paper over the other, bigger missing piece, which is the ability to save an in-progress conflicted merge and restore it later.)

---

<sup>1</sup>Note, however, that the old-style non-interactive `git-rebase--am` still uses `git format-patch` and `git am`.  This process does not work as well in some cases with renamed files and cannot copy a "makes no changes" commit, but does run *faster*.  In most cases, both this and the cherry-pick style should give the same results, despite the change in underlying mechanism, especially since the cherry-pick variant *defaults* to not copying a "makes no changes" commit.

<sup>2</sup>The rebase also subtracts away any commits that exist in the `mainline` set and have the same `git patch-id` as any commits in the `feature` set, and of course, by default, it subtracts away all merges.

Comment: This is much clearer now. I think I had long seen these processes as kind of transactions. Either you go all the way to a satisfying state, or you rollback everything to square one. Which was a useful but somewhat naive approach to what really happens at plumbing level. Thanks to eftshit0 and chepner also!

Answer (score 8):

`--abort` will take you back to  where you where before you started the cherry-pick operation whereas `--quit` will get out of the operation and keep you at the revision you are currently on. I can't think of a use case other than you wanting to go on a different direction after you hit a revision that could not be automagically cherry-picked,  which is why cherry-pick stopped in the first place,  right?

Comment: Hmm... I still don't get it. I have to read more in details about the whole cherry-picking process.

Comment: I think the difference is when there are multiple commits being cherry-picked. `--abort` would undo any commits you already merged, while `--quit` would leave those in place.