# does --quit leave you with a clean index and worktree after a rebase or a cherry-pick operation?

Tags: git

I know that --quit does not change your HEAD pointer, so any commits made successfully during a rebase or cherrypick are still there.

But what I'm unsure of is, in case a conflict happened during a cherry-pick or a rebase, whether using --quit clear the changes brought about by the conflict, such as the successfully added changes, the conflict markers in the working directory, the multiple versions in the index etc ?

The [git rebase documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#Documentation/git-rebase.txt---quit) has the following:

> --quit Abort the rebase operation but HEAD is not reset back to the original branch. The index and working tree are also left unchanged as
> a result.

the [cherry-pick documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick#Documentation/git-cherry-pick.txt---quit) is less clear about the effects on the index and work tree:

> --quit
> Forget about the current operation in progress. Can be used to clear the sequencer state after a failed cherry-pick or revert.

But this otherwise [excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55431768/whats-different-between-abort-and-quit-as-sequencer-subcommands-for-ch/55433382#55433382) in SO has the following:

> But if you choose --quit, Git terminates the rebase without moving HEAD, so that you wind up with:

> but a **clean index and work-tree**. So you don't have to be clever enough to attach a branch name before the --quit.

So which is it ? I know that in a merge --quit will not clear the mess that a merge conflict makes in your index and work tree, it just abandons the merge head state. is it different in case of a cherry pick or a rebase ?

Comment: Your third link is broken it seems. I guess you went for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55433382/1057485)?

Comment: Yup thats the one, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on the state you had at the time you issue the `--quit`: Git just stops here.  I'll update the other answer to indicate that you can then `git reset --hard` to make it "clean" if you want, or leave it "dirty" if you want.

Comment: Oh hello there! Small world huh. I just wanted to confirm, because usually in a merge conflict, your index and work tree are not clean at all, unless you do it yourself and then quit. So thank you so much for clearing that out. I should mention that I tried to make an edit to the answer, and it said the edit queue is full.